# Use of 'using' keyword to make inherited constructor public

Tags: c++, inheritance, testing, c++11, using

I am trying to test protected methods and constructors of my class. For this purpose, I tried to subclass it, and re-export its members as public with C++11 `using` keyword:

```
class Foo {
  protected:
   Foo(int i) {}
   void run() {}
};

class TestableFoo : public Foo {
  public:
   using Foo::Foo;
   using Foo::run;
};

int main() {
  TestableFoo foo(7);
  foo.run();
}
```

However, both g++ and clang++ fail to compile it, producing the following error:

```
test.cpp:13:15: error: ‘TestableFoo::TestableFoo(int)’ is protected
    using Foo::Foo;
               ^
test.cpp:18:16: error: within this context
   TestableFoo foo(7);
                    ^
```

TestableFoo constructor is still protected, even though `run` method becomes public (I confirmed it separately). Why is that so? I could understand either decision (inheriting vs. overwriting visibility), but why is there an inconsistency between methods and constructors?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014240/c11-declaring-factory-a-friend-of-base-class - but doesn't answer *why*

Comment: The "why" is probably because otherwise it would change the accessibility of *all* the constructors, which might be considered a worse evil than the inconvenience of not being able to inherit them in this situation. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Standard explicitly states that inherited constructors retain their access levels:

**12.9 Inheriting constructors [class.inhctor]**

> 1 A using-declaration (7.3.3) that names a constructor implicitly
>   declares a set of inheriting constructors. The candidate set of
>   inherited constructors from the class `X` named in the using-declaration
>   consists of actual constructors and notional constructors that result
>   from the transformation of defaulted parameters as follows:

[list of cases omitted]

> 4 **A constructor so declared has the same access as the corresponding
>   constructor in X**. It is deleted if the corresponding constructor in `X`
>   is deleted (8.4).

You can call it directly of course:

```
TestableFoo(int i) : Foo(i) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is conform with what the standard says (ISO/IEC 14822:2011 12.9, §4) :

> A constructor so declared has the same access as the corresponding constructor in X.

where `X` is the base class from which the constructors are inherited.

To get the desired behaviour, you can use :

```
class TestableFoo : public Foo {
  public :
    TestableFoo(int i) : Foo(i) { }
    using Foo::run;
};
```