# Using base class constructor when it is protected

Tags: c++, c++11, using-directives

I would like to use the base class constructor in a subclass, the base class constructor is protected so it cannot be instantiated without a subclass.

```
class A {
protected:
    A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() : A() {}
};
```

but I cannot use a using directive like this without the compiler complaining that `B::B()` is protected, even though the using is in the public block.

```
class B {
public:
    using A::A;
};
```

Where is this behavior specified?

EDIT

I attempted to simplify the example, and did not check to see it compiles, apparently with a trivial constructor it works, but this code does not compile

```
class A {
protected:
    A(int x) {}
};

class B : public A{
public:
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
  B b(4);
}
```

with error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:12:8: error: 'A::A(int)' is protected within this context
   B b(4);
        ^
main.cpp:3:5: note: declared protected here
     A(int x) {}
     ^

exit status 1
```

Comment: _"so it cannot be instantiated without a subclass"_

Comment: I think you forgot to make `B` inherit from `A` in your example. It I make `B` derive from `A`, the examples seem to work fine.

Comment: The code does not support your question, please create a [mcve]

Comment: Obviously you meant to inherit from A, but did you mean to do it publicly, privately or protectedly?  And [what is your error exactly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33b66b6b7d39ecf3)?

Comment: You forgot to inherit in the second `class B`. Your code works fine with inheritance ([demo](https://ideone.com/qp9BAg)).

Comment: do you really want to know where this is specified ( in the c++ standard ) or how to fix it?

Comment: I cannot [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fdd280c8a9ab56d) what you're claiming.

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question to the correct code example

Comment: The answer is "because the standard says so" - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24015931/241631

Comment: The answer to your question can be found at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.inhctor#4.

Comment: Why do you think you need the `usimg A::A` directive?